# What's UserNotification framework's equivalent of didReceive notification: UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, uiapplication, usernotifications

I already knew about this code which can be used before iOS 10:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

}
```

However, it's depreciated so I just want to ask is there any method that is  equivalent to the `UserNotifications` framework or I just have to get by with this warning?

Note that I want the app to do something when app is in the background or is terminated.

Comment: see this https://alessiopapazzoni.com/2016/09/29/ios-10-uilocalnotification-is-dead/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecated method was notifying delegate when the app received notification while in foreground. Now `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` does the same thing:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    UNUserNotificationCenter, 
    willPresent: UNNotification, 
    withCompletionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
)
```

> Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

[Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate)

Comment: what about when app is terminated or in the background?

Comment: @TianXi, nothing. You can't rise your app with a notification. But you can handle notification actions, in this case the app will be running in the background. Also, I gave direct answer to your question, please, accept it.